# Button onclick open window when data is set

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, button

My original idea is when a form is submitted I get the required id to download the right content through javascript with `window.open()` but it's getting blocked because it's not coming directly from a button click. So how can I make it part of an onlclick event after the button is set?

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['redownload'])) {

    $row3 = Users::redownloadContent($_POST['redownload_id']);

    ?>
    <script>
        window.open('<?php echo $row3["content"] ?>');
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redownload_id" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
<button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit" name="redownload">Download latest version</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use redirect:

```php
if (isset($_POST['redownload'])) {

    $row3 = Users::redownloadContent($_POST['redownload_id']);

    header("Location: ".$row3["content"]);
}
```

If you want to use JS you can simply do:

```
if (isset($_POST['redownload'])) {

    $row3 = Users::redownloadContent($_POST['redownload_id']);

    ?>
    <script>
        window.location.href = "<?php echo $row3["content"] ?>";
    </script>
    <?php
}
```